# Using a variable when traversing an array with yq causes strange behaviour

Tags: yaml, jq, yq

Consider a file `test.yaml`:

```
- name: Cathy
  has: apples
- name: Bob
  has: bananas
```

and a request:

```
yq '.[] | .name as $n | {"n": $n}' test.yaml
```

the output is:

```
n: Cathy
n: Bob
n: Cathy
n: Bob
```

which looks strange, because I expect only two values. Also when I use only a value of the variable with no expression:

```
yq '.[] | .name as $n | $n' test.yaml
```

it works ok:

```
Cathy
Bob
```

Any advice how to use a variable for traversing arrays?

P. S. In `jq` the command

```
echo '{"list": [{"name": "Cathy", "has": "apples"}, {"name": "Bob", "has": "bananas"}]}' | jq '.list[] | .name as $n | {"n": $n}'
```

works as expected

Answer (score 4):

[mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), the Go implementation of yq (which you are using) has its own rules of processing, which sometimes differ from how jq would handle things. If you want vanilla jq experience on YAML files, use [the other implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of yq, [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), which is just a wrapper on jq, written in Python. Using that, you'd get:

```bash
yq -y '.[] | .name as $n | {"n": $n}' test.yaml
```

```yaml
n: Cathy
---
n: Bob
```

If you want to keep using mikefarah/yq, use parens to explicate the context:

```bash
yq '(.[] | .name) as $n | {"n": $n}' test.yaml
```

```yaml
n: Cathy
n: Bob
```

And if you want to include document separators with mikefarah/yq, append `split_doc`:

```bash
yq '(.[] | .name) as $n | {"n": $n} | split_doc' test.yaml
```

```yaml
n: Cathy
---
n: Bob
```

As you can imagine from seeing the outputs, these are not the only differences between the two implementations. Generally speaking, mikefarah/yq is more versatile as it reaches out to YAML features that are not representable in JSON, and hence kislyuk/yq wouldn't cover them. On the flipside, this makes coding with mikefarah/yq less succinct than it is with plain jq used by kislyuk/yq.

Here's yet another one to try: [itchyny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq) is a Go rewrite of jq which can also handle YAML inputs and YAML outputs.

```bash
gojq --yaml-input --yaml-output '.[] | .name as $n | {"n": $n}' test.yaml
```

```yaml
"n": Cathy
---
"n": Bob
```

---

EDIT: As it [turned out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75524947/using-a-variable-when-traversing-an-array-with-yq-causes-strange-behaviour#comment133252138_75525006), the variable was believed to be necessary to keep reference when loading a file whose path was part of the context, while data from the loaded file's contents should be merged with other parts of the original context. Specifically, the attempt looked like

```bash
# fails with mikefarah/yq
yq '.[] | load(.path) as $x | {"a": $x.a, "b": $x.b, "c": .c}' test.yaml
```

But the loading and merging can be achieved by making use of different (nested) context levels, and as such with using no variable bindings at all. While loading and extracting the external file is performed in a parens-enclosed subcontext, by being itself embedded into the original iteration context, the merging can then be achieved by simple addition (if the parts do not collide), or an intermediate array otherwise. In any case, the resulting entity can then be reshaped at will.

```bash
# works with mikefarah/yq
yq '.[] | (load(.path) | {"a": .a, "b": .b}) + {"c": .c}' test.yaml
```

Comment: `yq '(.[] | .name) as $n | {"n": $n}' test.yaml` is not what I am looking for, because I want to keep in `.` the full structure of the object runned against in traversal. This approach only selects the `.name` attribute, but what if I want `.has` attribute also?

Comment: @klimenkov Given your sample input, can you provide your expected output that includes `.has`? It'll make things easier to understand where we are going.

Comment: Sure, I expect `yq '.[] | .name as $n | {"n": $n, "h": $n + " " + .has}' test.yaml` give me
{n: Cathy, h: Cathy apples} {n: Bob, h: Bob bananas} (I use JSON-like syntax to fit it in one line)

Comment: @klimenkov Btw, why would you want to use a binding here at all? `yq '.[] | {"n": .name, "h": (.name + " " + .has)}'` would already do.

Comment: Suppose, I have a `.path` attribute (instead of `.name`) which contains a path to another yaml file, which I want to load and use later, so I this case I would traverse an array and use a loaded file in a variable and load every document only once
`yq '.[] | load(.path) as $x | {"a": $x.a, "b": $x.b, "c": .c} test.yaml`

Comment: Then try something along the lines of `yq '.[] | (load(.path) | {"a": .a, "b": .b}) + {"c": .c}`

Comment: I edited my answer to your previous question. I used in the output also an attribute from the current object with the attributes from a loaded yaml

Comment: @klimenkov I edited mine as well to include `.c`

Comment: Oh, thats seems working, but I dont like this unexpected _product_ behaviour or I just dont know how to make it _flat_

Comment: @klimenkov Once the object is composed as a single item, you can reshape it as you see fit.

Comment: Please, add to your question this trick with adding a map and remove the information about document separators, because my question was only about handling a variable in array traversal, not splitting documents

Comment: @klimenkov I will edit my answer (soon) to include a synopsis of the topic's evolution in the comments, but I would also argue to keep the document separation aspect as producing that initial stream with `.[]` effectively creates multiple documents, even in YAML's sense. Whether or not you want to mark them as such is what this part of my answer was about.